# Is it possible to ignore the program's stdout while running valgrind?

Tags: valgrind

I use the following command to run `valgrind`. But the `./main`'s output will be mixed with the output of `valgrind`. I want to keep `valgrind`'s output to stdout. Is there a way to ignore `./main`'s stdout? Thanks.

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind --dump-instr=yes --collect-jumps=yes --callgrind-out-file=/dev/stdout ./main
```

Comment: The below works, at least interactively.
It is however unclear what problem you want to solve.  valgrind --tool=callgrind --callgrind-out-file=/dev/tty date > d.out

Comment: It won't work if I use it in a script.

Comment: In a script, why not use a normal callgrind out file ? If really you want to avoid a temporary file, you could work with named pipes.

Comment: @phd The goal seems pretty clear to me: write the callgrind output to standard output, but suppress the target process output at the same time. Named pipes aren't needed if you have `/proc/PID/fd` or `/dev/fd` at your disposal.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer But in particular with callgrind (and the options given in the question), there is not much you can do without launching a tool such as kcachegrind, callgrind_annotate, ... on the resulting callgrind output. Well, maybe writing on stdout can be of some use with simple one shot callgrind file post-processor ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/proc/$$/fd/1` to refer to the original standard output in the calling shell, before the redirection, like this:

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind --callgrind-out-file=/proc/$$/fd/1 /bin/echo foo > /dev/null
```

If the system does not support `/proc/$$/fd` but has `/dev/fd` (for the current process), this might work (within a script, using bash):

```
exec {old_stdout}>&1
valgrind --tool=callgrind --callgrind-out-file=/dev/fd/$old_stdout /bin/echo foo > /dev/null
```

Comment: Note that I still do not understand what problem we are solving.  Maybe it would be nice to describe it (e.g. "I cannot use a normal callgrind out file, because ...."). Possibly, we better solve this (better described) problem as part of valgrind/callgrind itself.

Comment: I want to use the pipeline |. Using a file making it not possible to use pipeline as a one liner.

Comment: This one liner will work: "valgrind --tool=callgrind --callgrind-out-file=$PWD/c.out  your_program; kcachegrind $PWD/c.out; rm $PWD/c.out".  And of course, you can put that in a script, so that it becomes a one word:  my_callgrind your_program your_program_args